# cookies set in one controller are not accessed in other controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies

i have set the cookies in one controller and want to check whether it is set in the other controller. 
my controller where i set the cookie data is

```
app.controller('CtrlVehicle', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $location, $timeout) {
$scope.viewed_status = $.cookie('view_status');

alert($scope.viewed_status);

    $scope.skip_details = $.cookie('skip_details');

    $(".lead_form").submit(function ()
    {
 $.cookie('view_status', "viewed");
  });
 $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function () {
//        alert()
    });

    var my_array = [];

    //alert(JSON.stringify(my_array));

    if ($cookieStore.get('saved'))
    {
        //alert();
        my_array = $cookieStore.get('saved');
    }

    $new = [];

    if (my_array.length >= 1)
    {



        for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++)
        {

            //delete my_array[i];
            //alert( JSON.stringify(my_array[i][0].vin)) ;
            if ((my_array[i].vin))
            {
                $new.push(my_array[i].vin);

            }


        }

    }



    $rootScope.saved_array = $new;

});
```

and i want to alert this data when CtrlUsed controller is called

Here is the other conrtoller.

```
app.controller('CtrlUsed', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $location, $timeout) {

    $scope.viewed_status = $.cookie('view_status');

   alert($scope.viewed_status);

    });
```

when i try to alert in CtrlVehicle its set and says "viewed" but when i try with CtrlUsed it says "undefined"

Comment: A better way to do is use service. set the cookie from service and can get where ever you want using dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never setting cookies in above code given in questions.

And instead of using `$cookieStore`  try using `$cookies` and set/get it like following:-

```
$cookies.put('user', ValueOfUser);
$cookies.get('user');
```

Also get the cookie with same name as you're setting...

Comment: $.cookie('view_status', "viewed"); i set the cookie in this line in the above code @Rakeschand

Comment: So you're setting by 'view_status' name  and gettin by 'saved'??